# Update table using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

I wrote a PHP function, that takes two input parameters and updates a database table.

```
function updateTable($a, $b){

        $query = "UPDATE myTable
                  SET dataUpload=CURDATE(), lastUpdate=NOW()
                  WHERE Code IN(SELECT Code FROM myTable2 WHERE QR = ?) AND aid=?";
        $stmt=$connectiondb->stmt_init();
        if (!($stmt = $connectiondb->prepare($query))) {
          echo "Prepare failed: (" . $connectiondb->errno . ") " . $connectiondb->error;
           $firephp->log("prepare failed in update myTable");
        }
        if (!$stmt->bind_param('si',$a, $b)) {
          echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
          $firephp->log("bind failed in update myTable");
        }
        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
          echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
          $firephp->log("execute failed in update myTable");
        }

        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();
}
```

where:

```
$connectiondb = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
```

If I call this function, inside PHP code, for example in this way:

```
updateTable('923TRU234',1100);
```

it does not work, but if I call the update statement on the MySQL database:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET dataUpload=CURDATE(), lastUpdate=NOW()
WHERE Code IN(SELECT Code FROM myTable2 WHERE QR = '923TRU234') AND aid=1100
```

it works!

Comment: Try this: `function updateTable($a, $b, $connectiondb, $firephp) {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are referring to your connection properly.  You refer to `$connectiondb` as though it is a global, but it looks like you defined it outside of your function. You don't use the command `global $connectiondb;` inside the function.  So, PHP doesn't know about your connection, and treats `$connectiondb` as undefined.

See [this page on variable scopes in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for more information about how this works.

Also, if you can shed more light than "it doesn't work," it will be easier to help you troubleshoot.  What *does* happen?

Comment: $connectiondb is defined as global. In fact some rows next that code I make other CRUD operation using the same $connectiondb

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "defined as global."  If you meant that you initiated it outside of any function, then, yes, it is a global variable, but your function's code doesn't know that.  You still need `global $connectiondb;` inside the function.  See the link above for more information.

Comment: ok, you are right, I have modified my code adding a third parameter ($dbconnection) and now it works! thank you